# Why file audio is not playing after receiving UDP packet?

Tags: python, audio, udp

The script below has to play an audio file (.wav) after receiving an UDP packet BUT it does not work. Why?

```
import pygame
import socket

# set UDP port
UDP_PORT = 5005

# audio (.wav) file path
AUDIO_FILE_PATH = "/home/rpi/mixkit-emergency-alert-alarm-1007.wav"

def play_audio(file_path):
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start UDP socket UDP
    udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    udp_socket.bind(("", UDP_PORT))
    print("Listening UDP port", UDP_PORT)

    while True:
        data, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        message = data.decode("utf-8")
        print("Message received:", message)

        # if msg received, play audio file
        if message == "play_audio":
            play_audio(AUDIO_FILE_PATH)
```

I tested it with following command:

`echo "play_audio" | nc -u -w1 192.168.8.120 5005`

The message was received but no audio was played.

THEN, I tried only the script to test audio, without UDP server, and it audio file was played correctly. Here below the script to test only audio:

```
import pygame

# Imposta il percorso del file audio (deve essere un file WAV)

AUDIO_FILE_PATH = "/home/rpi/mixkit-emergency-alert-alarm-1007.wav"

def play_audio(file_path):

    pygame.mixer.init()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)

    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():

        continue

if __name__ == "__main__":

    play_audio(AUDIO_FILE_PATH)
```

Does anyone can help me to understand why the program with UDP server together with audio playing does not work?

Comment: The "message was received" but did the `message == "play_audio"`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found my error.

Using `echo "play_audio" | nc -u -w1 192.168.8.120 5005` does not work.

Using following simple python script that sends UDP message does work.

```
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "play_audio"

print("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
print("message:", MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```